# IE7 problems with displaying text in TD

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I can not figure out why the text inside the TD is not displayed in IE7. I am frustrated to the core cuz it works in FF! All I am trying to do is dynamically build a table onload... Any help will be greatly appreciated.
The complete script is at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Kxysg6md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [insertRow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp) and [insertCell](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp) to add Rows and Cells
Ex:

```
var row = table.insertRow();
row.id= rowid;

var headerCell = row.insertCell();
headerCell.colSpan = colspan;
headerCell.className = "rightAligned";
headerCell.innerHTML = "Header Text";
```

Comment: It's better to use properties than `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`, which are broken in IE. For example: `headerCell.colSpan = colspan;`

Answer (score 1):

use the `insertRow(-1)` to add a row instead, and `insertCell(-1)` to add a column

updated code: http://pastebin.com/mTym410P

Answer (score 0):

IE needs a TBODY. Just add it as the first child of your table and then append your rows and cells to that.