# Why is the colspan not working properly in this script? js bug or IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496041/ie7-problems-with-displaying-text-in-td) question I asked a little while back. The updated code is posted [here](http://pastebin.com/Q5V6SSKx). This to note is that i am looking to create a HTML table dynamically that looks similar to this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col3</td>
      <td>Col4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col3</td>
      <td>Col4</td>
    </tr>  

  </tbody>

</table>
```

I can get this done in markup but when I do it in js the colspan does not seem to work in IE7. Any hep will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_colspan.asp

The `colSpan` javascript property has a capital `S`.

Comment: OMG!! I am kicking myself that I did not catch that.